# Script to switch multiple keyboard layouts

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard-layout

I use Archlinux and Pantheon Shell from the ElementaryOS project, but which has an unpleasant [bug](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/220) with switching layouts. Now I use [this script](https://github.com/yamnikov-oleg/switch-layout/issues/6) to switch between layouts. It does not work perfectly (there is still a slight delay between switching), but faster than a standard switch. I also removed the indicator from the panel as unnecessary. Now I'm learning another language and I need to add another layout to the system.

Due to the fact that the python script in 50 lines is running slowly, I would like to use `setxkbmap us`, `setxkbmap ru`, `setxkbmap eo` to switch, which, unlike all of the above, work instantly. The question is how to combine them into a script, so that pressing `CAPSLOCK` turns on `US`, `SHIFT + CAPSLOCK` turns on `RU`, and `SHIFT + TAB` turns on `EO`? I have never written such scripts and have no idea how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something similar without making a script:
you can create a new keyboard layout merging English, Russian, Esperanto, and it will behave almost as you want:

first create a file on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` (or anywhere your keyboard config files are located, it could be `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/`, depending on your distro), and name the file with a name that doesn't make conflict with existing files (I named mine `oo`). And put a few lines in this file to make sure it works:

```
xkb_symbols "multi" {
include "us(basic)"
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
name[Group1] = "english";
name[Group2] = "esperanto";
name[Group3] = "russian";
key <CAPS> {[ISO_Next_Group, ISO_Prev_Group]};
key.type[group1]="FOUR_LEVEL";
key.type[group2]="FOUR_LEVEL";
key.type[group3]="FOUR_LEVEL";
key <AD01> {[], [scircumflex, Scircumflex], [Cyrillic_shorti, Cyrillic_SHORTI]};
};
```

Then try it with `setxkbmap oo -variant multi`.

- pressing `q` will write `q`. This example works for letter `q` only (but I can easily do it for other letters). It could write `ŝ` for Esperanto or `й` for Russian.
- typing `Caps` cycles between `us`, `eo` and `ru`, with `ISO_Next_Group` (do it three times and you will be back to `us` layout).
- typing `Shift + Caps` cycles in reverse order with `ISO_Prev_Group`.

If you don't like this way to cycle between layouts, you can use (change the `<CAPS>` line in the file) :

```
key <CAPS> {[ISO_First_Group, ISO_Last_Group]};
```

- typing `Caps` goes to `us` layout, regardless on where you currently are, with `ISO_First_Group`.
- typing `Shift + Caps` goes to `ru` layout, regardless on where you are, with `ISO_Last_Group`.
- unfortunately, there is no `ISO_Second_Group`, so you can only have direct access to 2 layouts (but you can cycle if you want to use more than 2). There is a list of other similar key codes [here](https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/-/wikis/xdotool-list-of-key-codes).

How this file works:

- `xkb_symbols "multi" { ... };` is the name of the keyboard layout variant.
- `include "us(basic)"` includes `qwerty` layout, so you don't have to put `qwerty` keys in the config file.
- `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` if you want to use `Altgr` sometimes.
- `key <NAME>{ [group 1 content], [group 2 content], [group 3 content]};`, each group content is coma separated names for default key, key with `Shift`, key with `Altgr` ... up to 8 values. The content of the first group can be omitted here.

Note: group changing is faster than run `setxkbmap` each time.